# Fix INSERT conflict with FOREIGN KEY constraint issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I'm making a parking reservation system for a project and I'm encountering an issue when trying to insert my data into the database. I'm using C# and ADO.NET

The exact error is:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__ParkingRe__UserI__2057CCD0". The conflict occurred in database "Reservation", table "dbo.Users", column 'UserID'

```cs
public bool ReserveParkingSpot(Reservation reservation)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            // Check if the parking spot is available during the specified time
            string availabilityCheckQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ParkingReservations " +
                                            "WHERE ParkingSpotID = @ParkingSpotID " +
                                            "AND ((@StartTime >= StartTime AND @StartTime < EndTime) OR " +
                                            "(@EndTime > StartTime AND @EndTime <= EndTime))";
            using (SqlCommand availabilityCheckCommand = new SqlCommand(availabilityCheckQuery, connection))
            {
                availabilityCheckCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParkingSpotID", reservation.ParkingSpotID);
                availabilityCheckCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartTime", reservation.StartTime);
                availabilityCheckCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndTime", reservation.EndTime);

                int overlappingReservations = (int)availabilityCheckCommand.ExecuteScalar();

                if (overlappingReservations > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Parking spot is not available during the specified time.");
                    return false;
                }
            }

            // If the parking spot is available, update the IsFree status and proceed with the reservation
            string reserveParkingQuery = "UPDATE ParkingSpots SET IsFree = 0 WHERE ParkingSpotID = @ParkingSpotID; " +
                                         "INSERT INTO ParkingReservations (UserID, VehicleID, ParkingSpotID, StartTime, EndTime) " +
                                         "VALUES (@UserID, @VehicleID, @ParkingSpotID, @StartTime, @EndTime); " +
                                         "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();"; // Retrieve the auto-incremented ReservationID
            using (SqlCommand reserveParkingCommand = new SqlCommand(reserveParkingQuery, connection))
            {
                reserveParkingCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", reservation.UserID);
                reserveParkingCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VehicleID", reservation.VehicleID);
                reserveParkingCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParkingSpotID", reservation.ParkingSpotID);
                reserveParkingCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartTime", reservation.StartTime);
                reserveParkingCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndTime", reservation.EndTime);

                // Retrieve the auto-incremented ReservationID
                int reservationID = Convert.ToInt32(reserveParkingCommand.ExecuteScalar());

                Console.WriteLine($"Parking spot with ID {reservationID} reserved successfully!");
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error reserving parking spot: {ex.Message}");
        return false;
    }
}
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE Users 
(
    UserID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    [Name] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Email VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    [Password] VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Vehicles 
(
    VehicleID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    Brand VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Model VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [Year] INT NOT NULL,
    RegistrationPlate VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE ParkingReservations 
(
    ReservationID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    UserID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Users(UserID),
    VehicleID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Vehicles(VehicleID),
    ParkingSpotID INT,
    StartTime DATETIME,
    EndTime DATETIME,
    FOREIGN KEY (ParkingSpotID) REFERENCES ParkingSpots(ParkingSpotID)
);

CREATE TABLE ParkingSpots 
(
    ParkingSpotID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    IsFree BIT
);

INSERT INTO ParkingSpots (IsFree) 
VALUES (1), (1), (1), (1), (1),
       (1), (1), (1), (1), (1),
       (1), (1), (1), (1), (1),
       (1), (1), (1), (1), (1),
       (1), (1), (1), (1), (1);
```

I tried rewriting the whole query, but to no avail. It needs to save the data to the `ParkingReservations` table

Comment: Hi welcome to stack overflow. I would suggest checking that the ParkingSpotId you are trying to add the reservation is missing from the Parking spot table. Since it is a foreign key error and you only have one foreign key in your sample code. That seems like where the issue would be.

Comment: By ensuring that the foreign key values exist on the relevant table. The problem is the data you're trying to insert.

Comment: Also get into the habit of naming your contraints, then you don't have a name like `FK__ParkingRe__UserI__2057CCD0` and have no idea what object or columns it is related to.

Comment: As an aside its recommended **not** to use [`AddWithValue`](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: Might as well mention as well, I *hope* `Password` isn't a plain text value, and you are salting and hashing the value before it gets anywhere near your table.

Answer (score 1):

I saw that you tried to repost this question so I gave it a second look. It appears that your actual problem is that you are creating the `ParkingSpots` table after trying to reference it in the foreign key specified in the definition for `ParkingReservations`.

If you move the definition for `ParkingSpots` before the definition of `ParkingReservations` it should solve your issue.

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
    UserID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    [Name] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Email VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    [Password] VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Vehicles (
    VehicleID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    Brand VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Model VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [Year] INT NOT NULL,
    RegistrationPlate VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE ParkingSpots (
    ParkingSpotID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    IsFree BIT
);

CREATE TABLE ParkingReservations (
    ReservationID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    UUID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Users(UserID),
    CarID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Vehicles(VehicleID),
    SpotID INT,
    StartTime DATETIME,
    EndTime DATETIME,
    FOREIGN KEY (SpotID) REFERENCES ParkingSpots(ParkingSpotID)
);

INSERT INTO ParkingSpots (IsFree) VALUES (1), (1), (1), (1), (1),
                                         (1), (1), (1), (1), (1),
                                         (1), (1), (1), (1), (1),
                                         (1), (1), (1), (1), (1),
                                         (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)
```

As mentioned in the comments above by Thom A it would be good to get in the habit of specifying names for your foreign keys. This can save a lot of issues in the long run.

If you wish to name your constraints simply replace

```
FOREIGN KEY (ParkingSpotID) REFERENCES ParkingSpots(ParkingSpotID)
```

with

```
CONSTRAINT FK_ParkingReservations_ParkingSpots FOREIGN KEY (SpotID) REFERENCES ParkingSpots(ParkingSpotID)
```

Where `FK_ParkingReservations_ParkingSpots` is the name of the constraint

Comment: If this solves your question please mark it as the answer.